# What's the best way to respond to a question which can be answered simply by a "No."

Tags: discussion

I came across [Parsing string as a line of code in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607281/parsing-string-as-a-line-of-code-in-c) today.

The simplest answer to the question is "No.". I voted to close the question as off-topic with the following rationale.

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature that is not natively supported by the language. The quick answer to the question is a simple "No."

Is there a better way to respond to such questions?

Comment: SO users only like happy Yes answers.  *Proving* that No is an accurate answer takes a wholelotta work that's very rarely appreciated and is unpleasant to have to maintain.  And besides, saving a string to a file and compiling it is something you do every day.  Just don't bother.

Comment: @HansPassant, in theory, nothing can be done, not just in programming languages but in general, unless someone shows how it can be done. The "No." answer should not require any elaboration or proof.

Comment: It is never very hard to find 99 programmers that think something can't be done.  SO looks for the 1 that knows how.

Comment: @HansPassant very well said.

Comment: It's annoying to have to fill the remaining 13 characters.

Comment: If the question asks for a Yes/No answer, it seems rude to not simply provide it.   There are many questions for which an unequivocal 'No' is fine, eg 'Is it safe to write over the bounds of my C array', and 'Is it sensibly possible to develop and deliver a GUI app written in Haskell'.

Comment: I find it amusing that the quick answer to the example question is actually "Yes"

Comment: @JonChesterfield, by that analogy, almost everything is possible in a program. The existence of a [JavaScript PC emulator](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) is a testimony to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"It isn't possible" is a perfectly valid **answer**. I wouldn't say its off-topic at all (we get this question a lot in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) by the way).

The original comment; "Its not possible natively..." should have been an answer, ideally with any official sources that back the claim up.